# hibernate+c3p0+mysql max connections reached due to pools

Tags: java, hibernate, database-connection, connection-pooling, c3p0

I have configured c3p0 data source in my application using following code.

```
<bean id="globalDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${DbUrl}/${DbName}?useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true&amp;useSSL=false" />
    <property name="user" value="${DbUserId}" />
    <property name="password" value="${Password}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="14400" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="select 1" />
 </bean>
```

i have five different datasources with same configuration. On mysql side i have configured max_connections as 300. After 10 days with this live code mysql process list looks as follows with all sleeping connections:

- Database1: 70 connections
- Database2: 70 connections
- Database3: 70 connections
- Database4: 50 connections
- Database5: 40 connections

these all connections are in sleep state and mysql have reached to max limit of around 290 to 300 connections. Is there any way to release connections so that number of connections can come to at least min pool size?

for further info about it my application is very old and connections are not closed in many of hibernate transactions because its very hard to find  impact points if i use following line

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>
```

so i can not use above line in my hibernate-cfg.xml and for that reason i am also keeping alive my connections by "idleConnectionTestPeriod" to avoid timeout issue.

Please suggest best possible solution. i am thinking to use "maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" property of c3p0.

Comment: for further information i observed some more points: 1. when some high performance 7 or 8 queries runs parallel connections goes to 300 from normal 290 connections and not able to connect from even mysql CLI and CPU performance was around 100% spike for more than 1 hour.

Comment: Have you tried using the `maxIdleTimetout` value to see whether that helps those sleeping connections?  Basically, the c3p0 driver will not expire and discard any connection by default since it uses `0` for this, but any value above `0` will allow connections to be discarded, allowing the queue to shrink during inactivity periods.

Comment: i tried maxIdleTimetout also and it shrinks queue, but i faced timeout issue due to it.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is check for Connection leaks (which seem very likely to be your issue). See e.g. [C3P0 Spring Hibernate: Pool maxed out. How to debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773676/c3p0-spring-hibernate-pool-maxed-out-how-to-debug/41774651#41774651)

The best thing to do is to eliminate the Connection leaks. First you should set [unreturnedConnectionTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout) and  [debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces). See also [Configuring To Debug and Workaround Broken Client Applications](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients).

If this is an old and crufty thing and you can't or don't want to mess with it, you can workaround the issue by setting an [unreturnedConnectionTimeout](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout) and turning off [debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces). Collecting stack traces on every Connection checkout is a drag on performance. But first, to understand the issue, you should set both. If you decide you cannot or don't want to actually fix the problem, but wish to work around it, then unset or set to false `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`.