# SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, c3p0

Facing following problem: Everything was fine with the server connection until i decided to use c3p0 for connection pooling. Now (sometimes) i get a SQLNontransientConnectionException which occurs because new resources couldn't be acquired after 30 acquisition attempts. The behavior of this is pretty random, because often times when i locally restart the server it refuses to build because there is no connection found. Could this have anything to do with the way I instantiate my EntityManagerFactory?
I would be happy about any type of help

```
`WARNUNG: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@4ff43e8a -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30).
Last acquisition attempt exception:java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:550)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:537)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:527)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:512)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:480)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1807)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1624)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:637)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:351)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:224)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:184)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`
```

persistence.xml

```
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="3000"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="100"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads" value="8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
```

Edit 1: This is the full stacktrace

```
    java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:550)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:537)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:527)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:512)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:480)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1807)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:1624)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:637)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:351)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:224)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.Buffer.readInteger(Buffer.java:271)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaCapabilities.setInitialHandshakePacket(MysqlaCapabilities.java:62)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.readServerCapabilities(MysqlaProtocol.java:434)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.beforeHandshake(MysqlaProtocol.java:359)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.io.MysqlaProtocol.connect(MysqlaProtocol.java:1359)
    at com.mysql.cj.mysqla.MysqlaSession.connect(MysqlaSession.java:132)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:1754)
    ... 13 more
[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge1tv9nk20xsdnfi9dv|6f911326]-HelperThread-#0] WARN com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@55d58825 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
```

Edit 2: moved the configuration from persistence.xml to c3p0-config.xml

```
<c3p0-config>
<default-config>
    <property name="automaticTestTable">con_test</property>
    <property name="checkoutTimeout">30000</property>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod">30</property>
    <property name="initialPoolSize">10</property>
    <property name="maxIdleTime">30</property>
    <property name="maxPoolSize">100</property>
    <property name="initialPoolSize">20</property>
    <property name="minPoolSize">10</property>
    <property name="maxStatements">200</property>

    <user-overrides user="test-user">
        <property name="maxPoolSize">10</property>
        <property name="minPoolSize">1</property>
        <property name="maxStatements">0</property>
    </user-overrides>
</default-config>
```

Comment: hi, can you include the stack trace of the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` that is the cause of the problem?

Comment: @SteveWaldman there is no stack trace included. this is literally the last line of the stack trace. i think the arrayindexoutofboundsexception is caused by the 30 failed acquisition attempts: WARNUNG: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@710bedb7 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:

Comment: i very much doubt that. there are no arrays used as far as I can recall in c3p0's Connection acquisition logic. Much more likely is that all 30 of the attempts experience the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. you'll need to adjust your logging, either to not truncate stack traces, or else set a DEBUG log level for `com.mchange.v2.resourcepool` to see the individual failure stack traces.

Comment: @SteveWaldman oh sorry you were right, posted the full stack trace

Comment: Hi, sorry for the slow reply. It looks like this is a failure mode of MySQL when something is amiss in defining and authenticating the Connection. Please see here https://www.dezyre.com/questions/5061/sqoop-installation-steps for a nearly identical "Caused by" stack trace. Resolved by including the port explicitly in mysql jdbc url and granting permissions, apparently.

Comment: @SteveWaldman thanks a lot for your help. We already had imported the port and granted permission. Our problem is certainly not connecting to the server initially. It seems like once the connections are opened they aren't closed anymore and we get a "Too many connections" error. Increasing the max_size unfortunately hasn't helped either.

Comment: It sounds like you have a Connection leak, which c3p0 can help you debug. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773676/c3p0-spring-hibernate-pool-maxed-out-how-to-debug/41774651#41774651 or [c3p0's docs](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients).

Comment: @SteveWaldman thanks again for your help!! When i print out the processlist it just shows me a lot of sleeping threads i changed my relocated the c3p0 connection configuration from my persistence.xml to a c3p0-config.xml in my web-inf folder. That still didn't do it for me. Once a connection is opened it just stays idle and "sleeps" ignoring the fact i set the maxIdleTime to 30 seconds.

Comment: there's no problem using `persistence.xml`, you can set any c3p0 properties you could set in `c3p0-config.xml` there. c3p0 won't find config in the root `WEB-INF` directory of a web app, it should be `WEB-INF/classes`. and i sure didn't suggest looking at a process list, though it doesn't hurt. you probably have a Connection leak, and should understand and try c3p0 config params `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`.