# C3p0 datasource with PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-jdbc, c3p0

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour with our Java web application, configured to access a PostgreSQL database through C3p0 ComboPooledDataSource.
First of all, PostgreSQL server installation has default parameters, we didn't need to change any variable in it..

We run our queries using Spring JdbcTemplate, version 3.2.12.RELEASE. As it is for PostgreSQL, it is configured with default parameters.
Here it is our context configuration with C3p0 and Spring;

```
    <bean id="resoilDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <!-- access configuration -->
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/*****" />
    <property name="user" value="******" />
    <property name="password" value="******" />
    <!-- pool sizing -->
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="6" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="150" />
    <!-- refreshing connections -->
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="180" /> <!-- 3min -->
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="120" /> <!-- 3min -->
    <!-- timeouts e testing -->
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="120" /> <!-- 60 -->
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="false" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
</bean>

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="resoilDataSource"></property>
</bean>
```

Let me describe the problem we are encountering:
once we reach "maxPoolSize" of idle connections opened on Postgres side, this connections never expires, they remain in "idle" state and there's no way C3p0 will get any of them back for pooling..
I would expect that once one of these opened connections excess idle time, C3p0 is able to reuse it due to the "maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" parameter.
Unfortunately, this never happens.
I also tried to substitute C3p0 ComboPooledDataSource with Apache DBCP BasicDataSource, but nothing changed.

Before using PostgreSQL database for our application, our customers asked us to install our application integrating **other popular databases** instead of PostgreSQL (SQL Server and Oracle in particular) and we never experienced this behaviour.

Any ideas about what's going on it's truly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like your code is not closing connections (which returns them to the pool for reuse).

Comment: Yes. It sounds like a Connection leak, which c3p0 has built-in facilities for helping you debug. See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773676/c3p0-spring-hibernate-pool-maxed-out-how-to-debug/41774651#41774651 and [c3p0's docs](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients).

Comment: Hello you both, I can try to debug Connection leaks on my application, otherwise please consider this part of our application worked fine with other database I mentioned, without taking care directly of connections opening and closing. So I never really thought about connection leaks..