# Application stuck on retrieving connections from c3p0

Tags: java, postgresql, c3p0

I use centos 6.5 as the operating system and my version of postgres is postgreSql 9.3 and I use both jar c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar and postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6.jar.

my application and the database are in the same physical server that is very powerful and has this performance: 24 cpu, 256 GB memory

this is the configuration of the connection to the database: applicationContext-db.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN"
"http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
         <bean id="dataSource" class = "com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
       <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>

        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test"/> 

        <property name="user" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="password" value="postgres"/>
           <!-- pool sizing -->
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />

        <!-- retries -->
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="30" />
        <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000" /> <!-- 1s -->
        <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false" />

        <!-- refreshing connections -->
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="180" /> <!-- 3min -->
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="10" /> <!-- 1h -->

        <!-- timeouts and testing -->
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="30000" /> <!-- 30s -->
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="60" /> <!-- 60 -->
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" />
        <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" /> 

    </bean>
</beans>
```

and this the configuration of **postgresql.conf**:

```
# HEADER: This file was autogenerated at 2015-04-15 19:27:27 +0300
# HEADER: by puppet.  While it can still be managed manually, it
# HEADER: is definitely not recommended.
# -----------------------------
# PostgreSQL configuration file
# -----------------------------

max_connections = 1500 # (change requires restart)
# Note:  Increasing max_connections costs ~400 bytes of shared memory per
# connection slot, plus lock space (see max_locks_per_transaction).
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directories = '/tmp'   # comma-separated list of directories
                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)

# - Security and Authentication -

authentication_timeout = 5min       # 1s-600s
#ssl = off              # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ciphers = 'DEFAULT:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH'   # allowed SSL ciphers
                    # (change requires restart)
#ssl_renegotiation_limit = 512MB    # amount of data between renegotiations
#ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'       # (change requires restart)
#ssl_key_file = 'server.key'        # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ca_file = ''           # (change requires restart)
#ssl_crl_file = ''          # (change requires restart)
#password_encryption = on
#db_user_namespace = off

# Kerberos and GSSAPI
#krb_server_keyfile = ''
#krb_srvname = 'postgres'       # (Kerberos only)
#krb_caseins_users = off

# - TCP Keepalives -
# see "man 7 tcp" for details

#tcp_keepalives_idle = 0        # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_interval = 0        # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_count = 0       # TCP_KEEPCNT;
                    # 0 selects the system default


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RESOURCE USAGE (except WAL)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Memory -

shared_buffers = 8GB # min 128kB
                    # (change requires restart)
#temp_buffers = 8MB         # min 800kB
#max_prepared_transactions = 0      # zero disables the feature
                    # (change requires restart)
# Note:  Increasing max_prepared_transactions costs ~600 bytes of shared memory
# per transaction slot, plus lock space (see max_locks_per_transaction).
# It is not advisable to set max_prepared_transactions nonzero unless you
# actively intend to use prepared transactions.
#work_mem = 1MB             # min 64kB
#maintenance_work_mem = 16MB        # min 1MB
#max_stack_depth = 2MB          # min 100kB

# - Disk -

#temp_file_limit = -1           # limits per-session temp file space
                    # in kB, or -1 for no limit

# - Kernel Resource Usage -

#max_files_per_process = 1000       # min 25
                    # (change requires restart)
#shared_preload_libraries = ''      # (change requires restart)

# - Cost-Based Vacuum Delay -

#vacuum_cost_delay = 0          # 0-100 milliseconds
#vacuum_cost_page_hit = 1       # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_page_miss = 10     # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_page_dirty = 20        # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_limit = 200        # 1-10000 credits

# - Background Writer -

#bgwriter_delay = 200ms         # 10-10000ms between rounds
#bgwriter_lru_maxpages = 100        # 0-1000 max buffers written/round
#bgwriter_lru_multiplier = 2.0      # 0-10.0 multipler on buffers scanned/round

# - Asynchronous Behavior -

#effective_io_concurrency = 1       # 1-1000; 0 disables prefetching


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WRITE AHEAD LOG
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Settings -

#wal_level = minimal            # minimal, archive, or hot_standby
                    # (change requires restart)
#fsync = on             # turns forced synchronization on or off
#synchronous_commit = on        # synchronization level;
                    # off, local, remote_write, or on
#wal_sync_method = fsync        # the default is the first option
                    # supported by the operating system:
                    #   open_datasync
                    #   fdatasync (default on Linux)
                    #   fsync
                    #   fsync_writethrough
                    #   open_sync
#full_page_writes = on          # recover from partial page writes
#wal_buffers = -1           # min 32kB, -1 sets based on shared_buffers
                    # (change requires restart)
#wal_writer_delay = 200ms       # 1-10000 milliseconds

#commit_delay = 0           # range 0-100000, in microseconds
#commit_siblings = 5            # range 1-1000

# - Checkpoints -

#checkpoint_segments = 3        # in logfile segments, min 1, 16MB each
#checkpoint_timeout = 5min      # range 30s-1h
#checkpoint_completion_target = 0.5 # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
#checkpoint_warning = 30s       # 0 disables

# - Archiving -

#archive_mode = off     # allows archiving to be done
                # (change requires restart)
#archive_command = ''       # command to use to archive a logfile segment
                # placeholders: %p = path of file to archive
                #               %f = file name only
                # e.g. 'test ! -f /mnt/server/archivedir/%f && cp %p /mnt/server/archivedir/%f'
#archive_timeout = 0        # force a logfile segment switch after this
                # number of seconds; 0 disables


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REPLICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Sending Server(s) -

# Set these on the master and on any standby that will send replication data.

#max_wal_senders = 0        # max number of walsender processes
                # (change requires restart)
wal_keep_segments = 32      
#wal_keep_segments = 0      # in logfile segments, 16MB each; 0 disables
#wal_sender_timeout = 60s   # in milliseconds; 0 disables

# - Master Server -

# These settings are ignored on a standby server.

#synchronous_standby_names = '' # standby servers that provide sync rep
                # comma-separated list of application_name
                # from standby(s); '*' = all
#vacuum_defer_cleanup_age = 0   # number of xacts by which cleanup is delayed

# - Standby Servers -

# These settings are ignored on a master server.

#hot_standby = off          # "on" allows queries during recovery
                    # (change requires restart)
#max_standby_archive_delay = 30s    # max delay before canceling queries
                    # when reading WAL from archive;
                    # -1 allows indefinite delay
#max_standby_streaming_delay = 30s  # max delay before canceling queries
                    # when reading streaming WAL;
                    # -1 allows indefinite delay
#wal_receiver_status_interval = 10s # send replies at least this often
                    # 0 disables
#hot_standby_feedback = off     # send info from standby to prevent
                    # query conflicts
#wal_receiver_timeout = 60s     # time that receiver waits for
                    # communication from master
                    # in milliseconds; 0 disables


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# QUERY TUNING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Planner Method Configuration -

#enable_bitmapscan = on
#enable_hashagg = on
#enable_hashjoin = on
#enable_indexscan = on
#enable_indexonlyscan = on
#enable_material = on
#enable_mergejoin = on
#enable_nestloop = on
#enable_seqscan = on
#enable_sort = on
#enable_tidscan = on

# - Planner Cost Constants -

#seq_page_cost = 1.0            # measured on an arbitrary scale
#random_page_cost = 4.0         # same scale as above
#cpu_tuple_cost = 0.01          # same scale as above
#cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.005       # same scale as above
#cpu_operator_cost = 0.0025     # same scale as above
#effective_cache_size = 128MB

# - Genetic Query Optimizer -

#geqo = on
#geqo_threshold = 12
#geqo_effort = 5            # range 1-10
#geqo_pool_size = 0         # selects default based on effort
#geqo_generations = 0           # selects default based on effort
#geqo_selection_bias = 2.0      # range 1.5-2.0
#geqo_seed = 0.0            # range 0.0-1.0

# - Other Planner Options -

#default_statistics_target = 100    # range 1-10000
#constraint_exclusion = partition   # on, off, or partition
#cursor_tuple_fraction = 0.1        # range 0.0-1.0
#from_collapse_limit = 8
#join_collapse_limit = 8        # 1 disables collapsing of explicit
                    # JOIN clauses


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ERROR REPORTING AND LOGGING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Where to Log -

log_destination = stderr # Valid values are combinations of
                    # stderr, csvlog, syslog, and eventlog,
                    # depending on platform.  csvlog
                    # requires logging_collector to be on.

# This is used when logging to stderr:
logging_collector = on # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
                    # into log files. Required to be on for
                    # csvlogs.
                    # (change requires restart)

# These are only used if logging_collector is on:
log_directory = pg_log # directory where log files are written,
                    # can be absolute or relative to PGDATA
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log' # log file name pattern,
                    # can include strftime() escapes
#log_file_mode = 0600           # creation mode for log files,
                    # begin with 0 to use octal notation
log_truncate_on_rotation = on # If on, an existing log file with the
                    # same name as the new log file will be
                    # truncated rather than appended to.
                    # But such truncation only occurs on
                    # time-driven rotation, not on restarts
                    # or size-driven rotation.  Default is
                    # off, meaning append to existing files
                    # in all cases.
log_rotation_age = 1d # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                    # happen after that time.  0 disables.
log_rotation_size = 0 # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                    # happen after that much log output.
                    # 0 disables.

# These are relevant when logging to syslog:
#syslog_facility = 'LOCAL0'
#syslog_ident = 'postgres'

# This is only relevant when logging to eventlog (win32):
#event_source = 'PostgreSQL'

# - When to Log -

#client_min_messages = notice       # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   log
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error

#log_min_messages = warning     # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic

#log_min_error_statement = error    # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic (effectively off)

#log_min_duration_statement = -1    # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
                    # and their durations, > 0 logs only
                    # statements running at least this number
                    # of milliseconds


# - What to Log -

#debug_print_parse = off
#debug_print_rewritten = off
#debug_print_plan = off
#debug_pretty_print = on
#log_checkpoints = off
#log_connections = off
#log_disconnections = off
#log_duration = off
#log_error_verbosity = default      # terse, default, or verbose messages
#log_hostname = off
log_line_prefix = '----------------- %m --------------------------------------------------------\n  %a %u@%d %p \n %r \n %e' # special values:
                    #   %a = application name
                    #   %u = user name
                    #   %d = database name
                    #   %r = remote host and port
                    #   %h = remote host
                    #   %p = process ID
                    #   %t = timestamp without milliseconds
                    #   %m = timestamp with milliseconds
                    #   %i = command tag
                    #   %e = SQL state
                    #   %c = session ID
                    #   %l = session line number
                    #   %s = session start timestamp
                    #   %v = virtual transaction ID
                    #   %x = transaction ID (0 if none)
                    #   %q = stop here in non-session
                    #        processes
                    #   %% = '%'
                    # e.g. '<%u%%%d> '
#log_lock_waits = off           # log lock waits >= deadlock_timeout
#log_statement = 'none'         # none, ddl, mod, all
#log_temp_files = -1            # log temporary files equal or larger
                    # than the specified size in kilobytes;
                    # -1 disables, 0 logs all temp files
log_timezone = 'Asia/Aden'


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RUNTIME STATISTICS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Query/Index Statistics Collector -

#track_activities = on
#track_counts = on
#track_io_timing = off
#track_functions = none         # none, pl, all
#track_activity_query_size = 1024   # (change requires restart)
#update_process_title = on
#stats_temp_directory = 'pg_stat_tmp'


# - Statistics Monitoring -

#log_parser_stats = off
#log_planner_stats = off
#log_executor_stats = off
#log_statement_stats = off


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AUTOVACUUM PARAMETERS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#autovacuum = on            # Enable autovacuum subprocess?  'on'
                    # requires track_counts to also be on.
#log_autovacuum_min_duration = -1   # -1 disables, 0 logs all actions and
                    # their durations, > 0 logs only
                    # actions running at least this number
                    # of milliseconds.
#autovacuum_max_workers = 3     # max number of autovacuum subprocesses
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_naptime = 1min      # time between autovacuum runs
#autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 50   # min number of row updates before
                    # vacuum
#autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 50  # min number of row updates before
                    # analyze
#autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2   # fraction of table size before vacuum
#autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1  # fraction of table size before analyze
#autovacuum_freeze_max_age = 200000000  # maximum XID age before forced vacuum
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age = 400000000    # maximum Multixact age
                    # before forced vacuum
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 20ms    # default vacuum cost delay for
                    # autovacuum, in milliseconds;
                    # -1 means use vacuum_cost_delay
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = -1  # default vacuum cost limit for
                    # autovacuum, -1 means use
                    # vacuum_cost_limit


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLIENT CONNECTION DEFAULTS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Statement Behavior -

#search_path = '"$user",public'     # schema names
#default_tablespace = ''        # a tablespace name, '' uses the default
#temp_tablespaces = ''          # a list of tablespace names, '' uses
                    # only default tablespace
#check_function_bodies = on
#default_transaction_isolation = 'read committed'
#default_transaction_read_only = off
#default_transaction_deferrable = off
#session_replication_role = 'origin'
#statement_timeout = 0          # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
#lock_timeout = 0           # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
#vacuum_freeze_min_age = 50000000
#vacuum_freeze_table_age = 150000000
#vacuum_multixact_freeze_min_age = 5000000
#vacuum_multixact_freeze_table_age = 150000000
#bytea_output = 'hex'           # hex, escape
#xmlbinary = 'base64'
#xmloption = 'content'

# - Locale and Formatting -

datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
#intervalstyle = 'postgres'
timezone = 'Asia/Aden'
#timezone_abbreviations = 'Default'     # Select the set of available time zone
                    # abbreviations.  Currently, there are
                    #   Default
                    #   Australia (historical usage)
                    #   India
                    # You can create your own file in
                    # share/timezonesets/.
#extra_float_digits = 0         # min -15, max 3
#client_encoding = sql_ascii        # actually, defaults to database
                    # encoding

# These settings are initialized by initdb, but they can be changed.
lc_messages = C # locale for system error message
                    # strings
lc_monetary = C # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = C # locale for number formatting
lc_time = C # locale for time formatting

# default configuration for text search
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'

# - Other Defaults -

#dynamic_library_path = '$libdir'
#local_preload_libraries = ''


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOCK MANAGEMENT
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#deadlock_timeout = 1s
#max_locks_per_transaction = 64     # min 10
                    # (change requires restart)
# Note:  Each lock table slot uses ~270 bytes of shared memory, and there are
# max_locks_per_transaction * (max_connections + max_prepared_transactions)
# lock table slots.
#max_pred_locks_per_transaction = 64    # min 10
                    # (change requires restart)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# VERSION/PLATFORM COMPATIBILITY
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Previous PostgreSQL Versions -

#array_nulls = on
#backslash_quote = safe_encoding    # on, off, or safe_encoding
#default_with_oids = off
#escape_string_warning = on
#lo_compat_privileges = off
#quote_all_identifiers = off
#sql_inheritance = on
#standard_conforming_strings = on
#synchronize_seqscans = on

# - Other Platforms and Clients -

#transform_null_equals = off


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ERROR HANDLING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#exit_on_error = off            # terminate session on any error?
#restart_after_crash = on       # reinitialize after backend crash?


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONFIG FILE INCLUDES
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# These options allow settings to be loaded from files other than the
# default postgresql.conf.

#include_dir = 'conf.d'         # include files ending in '.conf' from
                    # directory 'conf.d'
#include_if_exists = 'exists.conf'  # include file only if it exists
#include = 'special.conf'       # include file


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CUSTOMIZED OPTIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Add settings for extensions here
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
temp_buffers = 32MB
work_mem = 64MB
checkpoint_segments = 32
max_wal_senders = 5
wal_keep_segments = 32
wal_level = hot_standby
data_directory = '/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data'
listen_addresses = '*'
log_min_duration_statement = 2min
port = 5432
effective_cache_size = 16GB
```

when the use of the application has become important and when the number of requests increases

I have this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:527)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 202 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@50e84eee -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1317)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 205 more
```

**note**: the number of users using the application is around 1500

I think the error is in the postgres configuration (postgresql.conf) and specifically in these two parameters:

```
shared_buffers
max_connections
```

I can not calculate well the value of max_connections (now is 1500 and it's huge in my opinion) and this value normally should be compatible with the parameters that are in the file applicationContext-db.xml and also should be compatible with server performance.

also in my application I have this code in order to make the reconnect when we have lost connection

```
protected Session getSession(String configFile) {
        if ((null != session) && session.isOpen()) {
            return session;
        } else if (null != sessionFactory) {
            Session s = currentSession.get();

            if ((null == s) || !s.isOpen()) {
                s = sessionFactory.openSession();
                currentSession.set(s);
            } else {
                try {
                    HibernateWork hibernateWork = new HibernateWork("SELECT 1 ");
                    s.doWork(hibernateWork);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("------ Connection is closed, reconnection start");

                    s = sessionFactory.openSession();
                    currentSession.set(s);
                }
            }

            return s;
        } else {
            Session s = currentSession.get();

            if ((null == s) || !s.isOpen()) {
                s = getSessionFactory(configFile).openSession();
                currentSession.set(s);
            }

            return s;
        }
    }
```

is there anyone who can help me to properly configure the connection pool settings

thank you in advance

**updated :**

I used the latest version of c3p0 which is c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar but the same problem of connection loss still exists:

```
    2017-12-03 11:32:08,414 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (ajp-0.0.0.0-8010-68) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
    2017-12-03 11:32:08,415 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (ajp-0.0.0.0-8010-68) An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
..........
..........
2017-12-03 11:32:08,423 ERROR [STDERR] (ajp-0.0.0.0-8010-130) Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.TimeoutException: A client timed out while waiting to acquire a resource from com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@49d523bd -- timeout at awaitAvailable()
2017-12-03 11:32:08,423 ERROR [STDERR] (ajp-0.0.0.0-8010-130)   at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1467)
```

I found after a search that some people have the same type of problem and they put this configuration in applicationContext-db.xml:

```
<property name="maxStatements" value="1100" />
<property name="checkoutTimeout" value="60000" />
```

I want to know your opinion for this change before putting it into production.

Comment: Your pool only allows 200 connections, so increasing `max_connections` on the server to 1500 doesn't do anything. It seems all your 200 connections in the pool are exhausted. This is very often caused by the application **not** returning connections properly to the pool

Comment: I try to manage this problem in my application using this method protected Session getSession(String config File) in order to make the reconnect when we have lost connection but without success

Comment: Echoing @a_horse_with_no_name, you may have a Connection leak. c3p0-0.9.1.1 is very, very old. I'd recommend you update to a more recent version. c3p0 has facilities to help you debug Connection leaks. See e.g. http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773676/c3p0-spring-hibernate-pool-maxed-out-how-to-debug/41774651#41774651 (but i don't remember whether a version as old as 0.9.1.1 had this implemented. probably.)

Comment: thank you for your response I will update the c3p0 and i will use c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar, but for the value 1500 in max_connections in postgresql.conf file  it should be set to 200 like the value in maxPoolSize or not

Comment: what about make this config <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="0" />  zero means wait indefinitely for a Connection to be checked-in or acquired when the pool is exhausted

Comment: until now I didn't set 0 to checkoutTimeout ,
first I will wait the result of test from my application using the previous changement : use c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar and mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar.

but i want to know your opinion to set 0 to checkoutTimeout , 
 is it a solution for my problem

Comment: I have updated my question, after put the last version of c3p0 :  c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar, i found the same problem,  i have another idea of change : increase the value of maxStatements and checkoutTimeout   but I want to know your opinion for this change before putting it into production.

Answer (score 0):

You must start closing your sessions. Its a typical resource leak.

Typical CRUD operation should look like this

```
Session s=getSession();
try{
  //do your work with session, save, load update whatever
 // optionally catch some exceptions
}finally{
  s.close(); // close session and return connection 
}
```

`s.close()` is what you are missing here.

`close()` is in `finally` block so it will be always executed, as well as in normal execution as while exception occur.

Remember this:

`SessionFactory` is **Thread safe** and **heavyweight** component, sho it should be created once, and shared accross whole application

`Session` is **Not Thread safe** and is **lightweight** components, thus it should be not shared accross application but created and closed asap.

Comment: I have changed the default method getSession  and I add this lines  else {
                try {
                    HibernateWork hibernateWork = new HibernateWork("SELECT 1 ");
                    s.doWork(hibernateWork);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("------ Connection is closed, reconnection start");

                    s = sessionFactory.openSession();
                    currentSession.set(s);
                }
            }

Answer (score 0):

for my crud method I have this **_BaseRootDAO** class :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Expression;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Order;

import com.test.hibernate.util.HibernateWork;


public abstract class _BaseRootDAO {

    public _BaseRootDAO () {}

    public _BaseRootDAO (Session session) {
        setSession(session);
    }



    protected static Map<String, SessionFactory> sessionFactoryMap;
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session session;
    protected final static ThreadLocal<Session> currentSession = new ThreadLocal<Session>();


    public Session getSession() {
        return getSession(
            getConfigurationFileName());
    }


    protected Session getSession(String configFile) {
        if ((null != session) && session.isOpen()) {
            return session;
        } else if (null != sessionFactory) {
            Session s = currentSession.get();

            if ((null == s) || !s.isOpen()) {
                s = sessionFactory.openSession();
                currentSession.set(s);
            } else {
                try {
                    HibernateWork hibernateWork = new HibernateWork("SELECT 1 ");
                    s.doWork(hibernateWork);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("------ Connection is closed, reconnection start");

                    s = sessionFactory.openSession();
                    currentSession.set(s);
                }
            }

            return s;
        } else {
            Session s = currentSession.get();

            if ((null == s) || !s.isOpen()) {
                s = getSessionFactory(configFile).openSession();
                currentSession.set(s);
            }

            return s;
        }
    }


    public void setSession (Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    /**
     * Configure the session factory by reading hibernate config file
     */
    public static void initialize () {
        com.dq.admincom.hibernate.model.dao._RootDAO.initialize(
            (String) null);
    }


    public static void initialize (String configFileName) {
        com.dq.admincom.hibernate.model.dao._RootDAO.initialize(
            configFileName,
            com.dq.admincom.hibernate.model.dao._RootDAO.getNewConfiguration(
                null));
    }

    public static void initialize (String configFileName, Configuration configuration) {
        if (null != sessionFactoryMap && null != sessionFactoryMap.get(configFileName)) return;
        else {
            if (null == configFileName) {
                configuration.configure();
                com.dq.admincom.hibernate.model.dao._RootDAO.setSessionFactory(
                    null,
                    configuration.buildSessionFactory());
            }
            else {
                configuration.configure(
                    configFileName);
                com.dq.admincom.hibernate.model.dao._RootDAO.setSessionFactory(
                    configFileName,
                    configuration.buildSessionFactory());
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set the session factory
     */
    public void setSessionFactory (SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Set the session factory
     */
    protected static void setSessionFactory (String configFileName, SessionFactory sf) {
        if (null == configFileName) configFileName = "";
        if (null == sessionFactoryMap) sessionFactoryMap = new HashMap<String, SessionFactory>();
        sessionFactoryMap.put(
            configFileName,
            sf);
    }


    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (null != sessionFactory) return sessionFactory;
        else return getSessionFactory(
        getConfigurationFileName());
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(String configFileName) {
        if (null == configFileName) configFileName = "";
        if (null == sessionFactoryMap)
            initialize(configFileName);
        SessionFactory sf = (SessionFactory) sessionFactoryMap.get(configFileName);
        if (null == sf)
            throw new RuntimeException("The session factory for '" + configFileName + "' has not been initialized (or an error occured during initialization)");
        else
            return sf;
    }

    /**
     * Close all sessions for the current thread
     */
    public static void closeCurrentSession () {
        Session s = currentSession.get();
        if (null != s) {
            if (s.isOpen()) s.close();
            currentSession.set(null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the session
     */
    public void closeSession (Session session) {
        if (null != session) session.close();
    }

    /**
     * Begin the transaction related to the session
     */
    public Transaction beginTransaction(Session s) {
        return s.beginTransaction();
    }

    /**
     * Commit the given transaction
     */
    public void commitTransaction(Transaction t) {
        t.commit();
    }


     public static Configuration getNewConfiguration (String configFileName) {
        return new Configuration();
     }

    /**
     * Return the name of the configuration file to be used with this DAO or null if default
     */
    public String getConfigurationFileName () {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Return the specific Object class that will be used for class-specific
     * implementation of this DAO.
     * @return the reference Class
     */
    protected abstract Class getReferenceClass();

    /**
     * Used by the base DAO classes but here for your modification
     * Get object matching the given key and return it.
     */
    protected Object get(Class refClass, Serializable key) {
        Session s = null;
        try {
            s = getSession();
            return get(refClass, key, s);
        } finally {
            closeSession(s);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used by the base DAO classes but here for your modification
     * Get object matching the given key and return it.
     */
    protected Object get(Class refClass, Serializable key, Session s) {
        return s.get(refClass, key);
    }

    /**
     * Used by the base DAO classes but here for your modification
     * Load object matching the given key and return it.
     */
    protected Object load(Class refClass, Serializable key) {
        Session s = null;
        try {
            s = getSession();
            return load(refClass, key, s);
        } finally {
            closeSession(s);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Used by the base DAO classes but here for your modification
     * Load object matching the given key and return it.
     */
    protected Object load(Class refClass, Serializable key, Session s) {
        return s.load(refClass, key);
    }

    /**
     * Return all objects related to the implementation of this DAO with no filter.
     */
    public java.util.List findAll () {
        Session s = null;
        try {
            s = getSession();
            return findAll(s);
        }
        finally {
            closeSession(s);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return all objects related to the implementation of this DAO with no filter.
     * Use the session given.
     * @param s the Session
     */
    public java.util.List findAll (Session s) {
        return findAll(s, getDefaultOrder());
    }

    /**
     * Return all objects related to the implementation of this DAO with no filter.
     */
    public java.util.List findAll (Order defaultOrder) {
        Session s = null;
        try {
            s = getSession();
            return findAll(s, defaultOrder);
        }
        finally {
            closeSession(s);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return all objects related to the implementation of this DAO with no filter.
     * Use the session given.
     * @param s the Session
     */
    public java.util.List findAll (Session s, Order defaultOrder) {
        Criteria crit = s.createCriteria(getReferenceClass());
        if (null != defaultOrder) crit.addOrder(defaultOrder);
        return crit.list();
    }


    protected Criteria findFiltered (String propName, Object filter) {
        return findFiltered(propName, filter, getDefaultOrder());
    }


    protected Criteria findFiltered (String propName, Object filter, Order order) {
        Session s = null;
        try {
            s = getSession();
            return findFiltered(s, propName, filter, order);
        }
        finally {
            closeSession(s);
        }
    }

    protected Criteria findFiltered (Session s, String propName, Object filter, Order order) {
        Criteria crit = s.createCriteria(getReferenceClass());
        crit.add(Expression.eq(propName, filter));
        if (null != order) crit.addOrder(order);
        return crit;
    }


    protected Query getNamedQuery(String name) {
        Session s = null;
        try {
            s = getSession();
            return getNamedQuery(name, s);
        } finally {
            closeSession(s);
        }
    }


    protected Query getNamedQuery(String name, Session s) {
        Query q = s.getNamedQuery(name);
        return q;
    }


    protected Query getNamedQuery(String name, Serializable param) {
        Session s = null;
        try {
            s = getSession();
            return getNamedQuery(name, param, s);
        } finally {
            closeSession(s);
        }
    }

    protected Query getNamedQuery(String name, Serializable param, Session s) {
        Query q = s.getNamedQuery(name);
        q.setParameter(0, param);
        return q;
    }


    protected Query getNamedQuery(String name, Serializable[] params) {
        Session s = null;
        try {
            s = getSession();
            return getNamedQuery(name, params, s);
        } finally {
            closeSession(s);
        }
    }


    protected Query getNamedQuery(String name, Serializable[] params, Session s) {
        Query q = s.getNamedQuery(name);
        if (null != params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                q.setParameter(i, params[i]);
            }
        }
        return q;
    }


    protected Query getNamedQuery(String name, Map params) {
        Session s = null;
        try {
            s = getSession();
            return getNamedQuery(name, params, s);
        } finally {
            closeSession(s);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Obtain an instance of Query for a named query string defined in the mapping file.
     * Use the parameters given and the Session given.
     * @param name the name of a query defined externally 
     * @param params the parameter Map
     * @s the Session
     * @return Query
     */
    protected Query getNamedQuery(String name, Map params, Session s) {
        Query q = s.getNamedQuery(name);
        if (null != params) {
            for (Iterator i=params.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) i.next();
                q.setParameter((String) entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        return q;
    }

    /**
     * Execute a query. 
     * @param queryStr a query expressed in Hibernate's query language
     * @return a distinct list of instances (or arrays of instances)
     */
    public Query getQuery(String queryStr) {
        Session s = null;
        try {
            s = getSession();
            return getQuery(queryStr, s);
        } finally {
            closeSession(s);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Execute a query but use the session given instead of creating a new one.
     * @param queryStr a query expressed in Hibernate's query language
     * @s the Session to use
     */
    public Query getQuery(String queryStr, Session s) {
        return s.createQuery(queryStr);
    }

    /**
     * Execute a query. 
     * @param query a query expressed in Hibernate's query language
     * @param queryStr the name of a query defined externally 
     * @param param the first parameter to set
     * @return Query
     */
    protected Query getQuery(String queryStr, Serializable param) {
        Session s = null;
        try {
            s = getSession();
            return getQuery(queryStr, param, s);
        } finally {
            closeSession(s);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Execute a query but use the session given instead of creating a new one.
     * @param queryStr a query expressed in Hibernate's query language
     * @param param the first parameter to set
     * @s the Session to use
     * @return Query
     */
    protected Query getQuery(String queryStr, Serializable param, Session s) {
        Query q = getQuery(queryStr, s);
        q.setParameter(0, param);
        return q;
    }

    /**
     * Execute a query. 
     * @param queryStr a query expressed in Hibernate's query language
     * @param params the parameter array
     * @return Query
     */
    protected Query getQuery(String queryStr, Serializable[] params) {
        Session s = null;
        try {
            s = getSession();
            return getQuery(queryStr, params, s);
        } finally {
            closeSession(s);
        }
    }


    protected Query getQuery(String queryStr, Serializable[] params, Session s) {
        Query q = getQuery(queryStr, s);
        if (null != params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                q.setParameter(i, params[i]);
            }
        }
        return q;
    }


    protected Query getQuery(String queryStr, Map params) {
        Session s = null;
        try {
            s = getSession();
            return getQuery(queryStr, params, s);
        } finally {
            closeSession(s);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Obtain an instance of Query for a named query string defined in the mapping file.
     * Use the parameters given and the Session given.
     * @param queryStr a query expressed in Hibernate's query language
     * @param params the parameter Map
     * @s the Session
     * @return Query
     */
    protected Query getQuery(String queryStr, Map params, Session s) {
        Query q = getQuery(queryStr, s);
        if (null != params) {
            for (Iterator i=params.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) i.next();
                q.setParameter((String) entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        return q;
    }

    protected Order getDefaultOrder () {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Used by the base DAO classes but here for your modification
     * Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated identifier. 
     * (Or using the current value of the identifier property if the assigned generator is used.) 
     */
    protected Serializable save(final Object obj) {
        return (Serializable) run (
            new TransactionRunnable () {
                public Object run (Session s) {
                    return save(obj, s);
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Used by the base DAO classes but here for your modification
     * Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated identifier. 
     * (Or using the current value of the identifier property if the assigned generator is used.) 
     */
    protected Serializable save(Object obj, Session s) {
        return s.save(obj);
    }

    /**
     * Used by the base DAO classes but here for your modification
     * Either save() or update() the given instance, depending upon the value of its
     * identifier property.
     */
    protected void saveOrUpdate(final Object obj) {
        run (
            new TransactionRunnable () {
                public Object run (Session s) {
                    saveOrUpdate(obj, s);
                    return null;
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Used by the base DAO classes but here for your modification
     * Either save() or update() the given instance, depending upon the value of its
     * identifier property.
     */
    protected void saveOrUpdate(Object obj, Session s) {
        s.saveOrUpdate(obj);
    }

    /**
     * Used by the base DAO classes but here for your modification
     * Update the persistent state associated with the given identifier. An exception is thrown if there is a persistent
     * instance with the same identifier in the current session.
     * @param obj a transient instance containing updated state
     */
    protected void update(final Object obj) {
        run (
            new TransactionRunnable () {
                public Object run (Session s) {
                    update(obj, s);
                    return null;
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Used by the base DAO classes but here for your modification
     * Update the persistent state associated with the given identifier. An exception is thrown if there is a persistent
     * instance with the same identifier in the current session.
     * @param obj a transient instance containing updated state
     * @param s the Session
     */
    protected void update(Object obj, Session s) {
        s.update(obj);
    }

    /**
     * Delete all objects returned by the query
     */
    protected int delete (final Query query) {
        Integer rtn = (Integer) run (
            new TransactionRunnable () {
                public Object run (Session s) {
                    return new Integer(delete((Query) query, s));
                }
            });
        return rtn.intValue();
    }

    /**
     * Delete all objects returned by the query
     */
    protected int delete (Query query, Session s) {
        List list = query.list();
        for (Iterator i=list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            delete(i.next(), s);
        }
        return list.size();
    }

    /**
     * Used by the base DAO classes but here for your modification
     * Remove a persistent instance from the datastore. The argument may be an instance associated with the receiving
     * Session or a transient instance with an identifier associated with existing persistent state. 
     */
    protected void delete(final Object obj) {
        run (
            new TransactionRunnable () {
                public Object run (Session s) {
                    delete(obj, s);
                    return null;
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Used by the base DAO classes but here for your modification
     * Remove a persistent instance from the datastore. The argument may be an instance associated with the receiving
     * Session or a transient instance with an identifier associated with existing persistent state. 
     */
    protected void delete(Object obj, Session s) {
        s.delete(obj);
    }

    /**
     * Used by the base DAO classes but here for your modification
     * Re-read the state of the given instance from the underlying database. It is inadvisable to use this to implement
     * long-running sessions that span many business tasks. This method is, however, useful in certain special circumstances.
     */
    protected void refresh(Object obj, Session s) {
        s.refresh(obj);
    }

    protected void throwException (Throwable t) {
        if (t instanceof HibernateException) throw (HibernateException) t;
        else if (t instanceof RuntimeException) throw (RuntimeException) t;
        else throw new HibernateException(t);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the given transaction runnable.
     */
    protected Object run (TransactionRunnable transactionRunnable) {
        Transaction t = null;
        Session s = null;
        try {
            s = getSession();
            t = beginTransaction(s);
            Object obj = transactionRunnable.run(s);
            commitTransaction(t);
            return obj;
        }
        catch (Throwable throwable) {
            if (null != t) {
                try {
                    t.rollback();
                }
                catch (HibernateException e) {handleError(e);}
            }
            if (transactionRunnable instanceof TransactionFailHandler) {
                try {
                    ((TransactionFailHandler) transactionRunnable).onFail(s);
                }
                catch (Throwable e) {handleError(e);}
            }
            throwException(throwable);
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            closeSession(s);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Execute the given transaction runnable.
     */
    protected TransactionPointer runAsnyc (TransactionRunnable transactionRunnable) {
        final TransactionPointer transactionPointer = new TransactionPointer(transactionRunnable);
        ThreadRunner threadRunner = new ThreadRunner(transactionPointer);
        threadRunner.start();
        return transactionPointer;
    }

    /**
     * This class can be used to encapsulate logic used for a single transaction.
     */
    public abstract class TransactionRunnable {
        public abstract Object run (Session s) throws Exception;
    }

    /**
     * This class can be used to handle any error that has occured during a transaction
     */
    public interface TransactionFailHandler {
        public void onFail (Session s);
    }

    /**
     * This class can be used to handle failed transactions
     */
    public abstract class TransactionRunnableFailHandler extends TransactionRunnable implements TransactionFailHandler {
    }

    public class TransactionPointer {
        private TransactionRunnable transactionRunnable;
        private Throwable thrownException;
        private Object returnValue;
        private boolean hasCompleted = false;

        public TransactionPointer (TransactionRunnable transactionRunnable) {
            this.transactionRunnable = transactionRunnable;
        }

        public boolean hasCompleted() {
            return hasCompleted;
        }
        public void complete() {
            this.hasCompleted = true;
        }

        public Object getReturnValue() {
            return returnValue;
        }
        public void setReturnValue(Object returnValue) {
            this.returnValue = returnValue;
        }

        public Throwable getThrownException() {
            return thrownException;
        }
        public void setThrownException(Throwable thrownException) {
            this.thrownException = thrownException;
        }
        public TransactionRunnable getTransactionRunnable() {
            return transactionRunnable;
        }
        public void setTransactionRunnable(TransactionRunnable transactionRunnable) {
            this.transactionRunnable = transactionRunnable;
        }

        /**
         * Wait until the transaction completes and return the value returned from the run method of the TransactionRunnable.
         * If the transaction throws an Exception, throw that Exception.
         * @param timeout the timeout in milliseconds (or 0 for no timeout)
         * @return the return value from the TransactionRunnable
         * @throws TimeLimitExcededException if the timeout has been reached before transaction completion
         * @throws Throwable the thrown Throwable
         */
        public Object waitUntilFinish (long timeout) throws Throwable {
            long killTime = -1;
            if (timeout > 0) killTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout;
            do {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
            while (!hasCompleted && ((killTime > 0 && System.currentTimeMillis() < killTime) || killTime <= 0));
            if (!hasCompleted) throw new javax.naming.TimeLimitExceededException();
            if (null != thrownException) throw thrownException;
            else return returnValue;
        }
    }

    private class ThreadRunner extends Thread {
        private TransactionPointer transactionPointer;

        public ThreadRunner (TransactionPointer transactionPointer) {
            this.transactionPointer = transactionPointer;
        }

        public void run () {
            Transaction t = null;
            Session s = null;
            try {
                s = getSession();
                t = beginTransaction(s);
                Object obj = transactionPointer.getTransactionRunnable().run(s);
                t.commit();
                transactionPointer.setReturnValue(obj);
            }
            catch (Throwable throwable) {
                if (null != t) {
                    try {
                        t.rollback();
                    }
                    catch (HibernateException e) {handleError(e);}
                }
                if (transactionPointer.getTransactionRunnable() instanceof TransactionFailHandler) {
                    try {
                        ((TransactionFailHandler) transactionPointer.getTransactionRunnable()).onFail(s);
                    }
                    catch (Throwable e) {handleError(e);}
                }
                transactionPointer.setThrownException(throwable);
            }
            finally {
                transactionPointer.complete();
                try {
                    closeSession(s);
                }
                catch (HibernateException e) {
                    transactionPointer.setThrownException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void handleError (Throwable t) {
    }


}
```

and this is **HibernateWork** class :

```
package com.test.hibernate.util;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import org.hibernate.jdbc.Work;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


/**
 * HibernateWork
 *
 * Oct 10, 2012
 */
public class HibernateWork implements Work {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HibernateWork.class);
    private String query;
    private ResultSet resultSet;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param query
     */
    public HibernateWork(String query) {
        super();
        this.query = query;
    }

    /**
     * execute
     */
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(this.query);

        this.resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
    }

    /**
     * @return the query
     */
    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    /**
     * @return the resultSet
     */
    public ResultSet getResultSet() {
        return resultSet;
    }
}
```

close method exist in _BaseRootDAO